# Android-Emulator network test with external IP?

Tags: android-emulator, network-programming, ip

I'm trying out some android programs requiring SQL, PHP and etc. So at the beginning, all IP-related configs are set to `10.0.2.2` which is actually the IP address back to the localhost from the emulator and it works out fine.

However is it possible to test the external connectivity out as well by using emulator?

I've set the port forwarding stuff correctly and the connectivity with HTTP outside is done. However when I modify the IP-related codes to my external IP and run it in the emulator, it takes like a couple minutes stuck in the loading screen and turns out failure (without any logs in the `LogCat` and Console).

So here just wanna know if that's possible to do the test with emulator and how to do so?